# Linux/Unix Command Needed for finding files on a particular date

Tags: linux, command

I need help finding files in a directory which contain a word/string and on a particular date.

Currently I am using this command:

```
find . -exec grep -l .string. {} \;
```

This command returns all the files containing that string in that directory. I would like to get those files on from a particular date, for example 12/24/2013.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Comment: Or better Linux And Unix: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the `find` command in Unix; you may get help on [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
find . -type f -exec grep 'string' {} \; -exec ls -l {} \; | grep 'Dec 24'
```

Which will search any files which contain the string `string`, and then execute `ls -l` on only those files, and finally, grep out any that match `Dec 24`.

This works because find will apply it's arguments in order, so only those that match previous results will be passed on.

Comment: Hi Donovan, I tried to find a way to close the thread but couldn't. Any suggestion.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Just click the 'checkmark' underneath the voting scores for the best answer.  It will change from outlined to solid green.  That means you've accepted that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you with grep:

```
find /path/to/find -type d -atime -7
```

The last parameter is days here 7 days before you can modify to particular dat ,atime is the file access time ,'d' is directory search for directory for find a file replace 'd' with 'f' give the path where to find and then finally make pipeline this with grep to string to search